# Pasar un atributo de clase por referencia a una variable local

Tags: php, poo, sqlite3

¡Qué tal gente! Tengo un PrintServer con el software [PaperCut PrintLogger](https://www.papercut.com/products/free-software/print-logger/) el cual genera unos archivos CSV (y HTML) con los log de impresión. Estoy haciendo un script que lee los CSV en introduce los datos en una base de datos, para posterior análisis.

En la base de datos tengo 3 tablas: `Printer`, `User` y `Activity`. Esta última tabla está relacionada con las otras 2 por sus id.
En otro método cargo en memoria 2 arrays atributos, `$this->printers` y `$this->users` con la información de impresoras (de la tabla `Printers`) y usuarios (tabla `Users`) que están actualmente en la base de datos (esto funciona perfecto).

Ahora, por cada registro del CSV leído, tengo un método que verifica que el nombre de la impresora aparezca en la tabla "`Printer`". Si no aparece, entonces inserta la impresora en esa tabla y actualiza `$this->printers` con esos datos para que no se vuelvan a insertar en posteriores comparaciones.

```
private function check_or_insert_printer_db($value) {
    // Inserta datos nuevos en las tablas de Printer o User
    $key_item = array_search($value, $this->printers);
    if($key_item === False) {
        // Si no se encuentra la impresora, insertarla en la tabla
        $query = "INSERT INTO Printer (prname) VALUES ('$value')";
        $this->dbconn->query($query);
        $id_item = $this->dbconn->lastInsertRowid();
        // Actualiza el array para no volver a insertar un elemento nuevo
        $this->printers[$id_item] = $value; 
    } else {
        // Si existe la impresora en la tabla, asignar el valor del id.
        $id_item = $key_item;
    }
    return $id_item; // retorna el ID relacionado
}
```

> Esto trabaja perfecto.

Aquí viene mi problema, que es más una duda. Quería que el método descrito también funcionara para "`Users`" ya que es exactamente la misma lógica que con "`Printers`". Así que modifiqué el método anterior y ahora tengo una variable local, `$arr_elements`, a la que le asigno la referencia de `$this->printers` o `$this->users`, según el caso.

```
private function check_or_insert_item_db($value, $table, $column) {
    // Inserta datos nuevos en las tablas de Printer o User
    $arr_elements = ($table == 'Printer') ? &$this->printers : &$this->users;
    $key_item = array_search($value, $arr_elements);
    if($key_item === False) {
        // Si no se encuentra el item, insertarlo en la tabla
        $query = "INSERT INTO $table ($column) VALUES ('$value')";
        $this->dbconn->query($query);
        $id_item = $this->dbconn->lastInsertRowid();
        // Actualiza el array para no volver a insertar un elemento nuevo
        $arr_elements[$id_item] = $value; 
    } else {
        $id_item = $key_item;
    }
    return $id_item; // retorna el ID relacionado
}
```

Pero aparece el siguiente error.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '&'

¿No se pueden asignar atributos por referencia a variables locales de un método? 
¿Hay una mejor forma de resolver este asunto sin tener que tener dos métodos separados para cada caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la razón del problema, y parece una una tontería, pero tenía razcándome la cabeza hace horas. Lo dejo como respuesta por si alguien le pudiera pasar lo mismo

No se si será una característica de PHP o un bug, o qué, pero parece que el `operador ternario` NO soporta asignaciones por referencia. Lo cual es extraño ya que he asignado cosas mucho más complejas con ellos. Pero bueno, tocará hacer una consulta en la base de conocimiento oficial de PHP a ver qué dicen.

Así que cambié

```
$arr_elements = ($table == 'Printer') ? &$this->printers : &$this->users;
```

por

```
if ($table == 'Printer') {
    $arr_elements = &$this->printers;
} else {
    $arr_elements = &$this->users;
}
```

Y santo remedio.

Comment: Al parecer no es un bug, asi es la sintaxis del operador ternario en PHP.  Otra forma de hacer lo mismo, pero se ve un poco confusa es `$arr_elements = &$this->{($table == 'Printer') ? 'printers' : 'users'};` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389928/can-you-pass-by-reference-while-using-the-ternary-operator